# Setting an randomly changing number hidden in a String as an Integer

Tags: java, string

I have a problem.
I want to set an Integer to a changing number that is hidden in a String. For example: "Hello world its me 666 again". Currently the number in the text is 666. But lets say every second this number changes. How do i let the program set this number as an integer or a string? Only that you understood me correctly. I want the value of the number in the moment when i execute the program but the number changes every second.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: ah noo... so. I have this text on a website... and my program should read this changing number and should tell it to me. I already opened a Stream to get this text from the website but now i want to save this changing number as an integer. Sorry for my English i dont know how to explain this better.

Comment: `updatedText = textFromWebsite.replaceFirst("\\d+", String.valueOf(newRandomNumber))`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your use case and this is not an optimal way to do this. Just to get you going, try this

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;

class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
       Random rand = new Random();
       int i=0;
       while(++i<100) {

           // a number between [0 - 1000]. change according to your usecase
           int n = rand.nextInt(1000);

           System.out.println("Hello world its me " + n + " again");
       }
   }
}
```

https://ideone.com/3rbxeO

Comment: A normal `for` loop would be better than that `int i=0; while(++i<100) {` logic.

Comment: ah noo... so. I have this text on a website... and my program should read this changing number and should tell it to me. I already opened a Stream to get this text from the website but now i want to save this changing number as an integer. Sorry for my English i dont know how to explain this better.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get a string with a random number on each time you execute your program, right? You can use ThreadLocalRandom for this kind of purpose:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int MIN = 100;
    final int MAX = 999;

    int i = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(MIN, MAX + 1);
    System.out.println("Hello world its me " + i + " again");
}
```

Comment: Why is `i` an `Integer`, not an `int`?

Comment: Exactly, `int` is suitable for this situation. Thanks!